# How do I test if string maches integer:integer with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to test if string matches integer:integer (ex: 9:4). 
I have tried

```
preg_match("[0-9]:[0-9]", $str)
```

but it's not correct.

Comment: What means *but it's not correct*? can you show samples with expected result? Hint mabe the `^`beginning of the string aand `$` and of string is missing . try `preg_match("^[0-9]:[0-9]$", $str)`

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ':'

Comment: I have tried your version and I get 
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^'

Comment: `preg_match("/[0-9]:[0-9]/", $str)` - you neglected the "delimiters" so it used `[` - which doesn't work out so well.

Comment: sorry must be `preg_match("/^[0-9]:[0-9]$/", $str)`. Also read the doc: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Just to be clear, you said it needs to match "integer:integer".  Should this support negative numbers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mark the start and end of the regular expression, *usually* with `/`.

Try this:

```
preg_match("/[0-9]:[0-9]/", $str)
```

One hint: you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

If you want to make sure that the string *only* contains digit:digit, use `^` as the marker for the start of the string and `$` for the end:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]:[0-9]$/", $str)
```

Also, add `+` to match numbers of more than one digit:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/", $str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9](:[0-9])*$
```

^ matches the start of the string, and $ matches the end, ensuring that you're examining the entire string. It will match a single digit, plus zero or more instances of a colons followed by a digit after it.